# Restful Webservice, Tomcat Error 500

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I got following problem. Iam coding a Restful Application with java and tomcat. Sofar this works fine. For example :

```
@GET
    @Path("/String/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getText()
    {
        String data = dothat();
        return data;
    }
```

(dothat(); connects to a java server, gets a string and returns it). When i call this mthod in my browser i CAN see the returned string.

However when i get a littlebit more complex and using a own class in a list like:

```
@GET
@Path("/test/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
static public Response test3()
{
    List<GpioPin> list = new ArrayList<GpioPin>();
    
    GpioPin one = new GpioPin(0, "HIGH", "GPIO-5");
    GpioPin two = new GpioPin(1, "LOW", "GPIO-1");
    
    list.add(one);
    list.add(two);
    
     GenericEntity<List<GpioPin>> result = new GenericEntity<List<GpioPin>>(list) {
        };
    
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(result).build();
}
```

I get a Error 500 code returned.

Myclass GpioPin:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GpioPin implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7583074316192202903L;
    private int boardPosition;
    private String gpioStatus;
    private String gpioPort;
    


    public GpioPin(int pos,String pinstate,String gpioPo)
    {
        boardPosition=pos;
        gpioStatus=pinstate;
        gpioPort=gpioPo;
    }
    public int getBoardPosition() {
        return boardPosition;
    }
    public void setBoardPosition(int boardPosition) {
        this.boardPosition = boardPosition;
    }
    public String getGpioStatus() {
        return gpioStatus;
    }
    public void setGpioStatus(String gpioStatus) {
        this.gpioStatus = gpioStatus;
    }

    public void setGpioPort(String gpioPort) {
        this.gpioPort = gpioPort;
    }
    
    public String getGpioPort() {
        return gpioPort;
    }
}
```

the strangest part about this: I get no error message... neither in the brwoser*img below* nor in any logs createt by Tomcat. [image: Error 500 without stacktrace]

After reading several threads here about logging in Tomcat i managed to swap logging to log4j. But also log4j on debug level does not tell me anything about an error.

I cant resolve this problem. Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to get your logging corrected because that will give you clues as to what the problem is.

I'll take a shot in the dark here and say that you need to remove the "static" keyword from the test3() method. So it would look like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/test/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response test3()
{
    List<GpioPin> list = new ArrayList<GpioPin>();

    GpioPin one = new GpioPin(0, "HIGH", "GPIO-5");
    GpioPin two = new GpioPin(1, "LOW", "GPIO-1");

    list.add(one);
    list.add(two);

     GenericEntity<List<GpioPin>> result = new GenericEntity<List<GpioPin>>(list) {
        };

    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(result).build();
}
```